# How to pre-create "business customers" in AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm building an on-boarding webapp to provision users for my LOB app. Most of my customers are "business customers", meaning they will ordinarily be directed to the v1 common endpoint by a custom policy, allowing them to auth against their own AAD tenant. The challenge is new users need follow-on provisioning in the LOB app as well (create db user, assign some permissions, etc).

What I'd like to do as part of on-boarding is call graphAPI to create what will become the federated user account in b2c, then with the new user objectId that comes back handle follow-on setup specific to my LOB app. Ideally when the user arrives for the first time, they would be redirected to auth against their own AAD, then map to the pre-created user in b2c, and finally land in the LOB app with an objectId that is already provisioned and ready.

Is this a supported scenario with some creative use of custom policies and graphAPI?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You can add a REST API call in the middle of a user journey: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw. So you should be able to create the user, assign permissions etc. using custom code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following options for this:

1. Create a local account user with the external email address and link the external user identity with this local account user.
2. Create an external account user with the external user identity.

**1. Create a local account user with the external email address**

Using Azure AD Graph API, you can [create a local account user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser), with the **signInNames** property of the **user** object being set to the email address of the external user:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": false,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "a-strong-random-password",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  }
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "john.smith@company.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** I recommend the **accountEnabled** property of the **user** object is set to **true** so that the end user can't log in with the local account password.

Using a custom policy, you can then add a new logic to find the local account user using the external email address and add the external user identity to this local account user, such as:

```xml
...
<!--
      Find the external account user using the external user identity.
-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="16" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
      <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!--
      If the external account user hasn't been found, then find the local account user using the external email address.
-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="17" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
      <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingEmailAddress" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!--
      If an account user hasn't been found, then create an external account user with the external user identity.
-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="18" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
      <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!--
      If the local account user has been found using the external email address, then add the external user identity to this local account user.
-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="19" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
      <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <!-- The following claim is output from the AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId technical profile. -->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>newUserCreated</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <!-- The following claim is output from the AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError technical profile. -->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>existingUserFoundByEmail</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteUserIdentity" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUserIdentity" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
...
```

**2. Create an external account user with the external user identity**

Using Azure AD Graph API, you can [create an external account user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser), with the **userIdentities** property of the **user** object being set to the object identifier of the external user:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": false,
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "mailNickname": "john.smith",
  "otherMails": [
    "john.smith@company.com"
  ],
  "userIdentities": [
    {
      "issuer": "https://sts.windows.net/{their-tenant-object-id}/",
      "issuerUserId": "{their-user-object-id}"
    }
  ],
  "userPrincipalName": "{guid}@{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

where **issuerUserId** must be set to the base64 encoding for the object identifier of the external user.

**Note:** In the Azure AD OpenID Connect technical profile, you might have to change the claim mapping for the **socialIdpUserId** claim from the **sub** claim to the **oid** claim, so that it matches the **userIdentities.issuerUserId** property of the **user** object:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - I was hoping I could do this without knowing `their-user-object-id`.  Idea being for B2C to brilliantly link the account and populate `their-user-object-id` for me when the user first arrives, perhaps by matching based on the email address.

Comment: Hi @MarkArnold I've updated the above answer to explain how you might implement the account linking on the email address.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Chris!

Comment: Chris - would you mind expanding on your last comment about mapping socialIdpUserId from sub to oid?  Seems there is now an issuerUserId mapping instead in the AAD OpenIDConnect tech profile.

Comment: Hi @MarkArnold. Yes, it seems the claim name has changed, from **socialIdpUserId** to **issuerUserId** in the policy samples. Nonetheless, the **sub** claim that is issued by Azure AD is a "pair-wise" identifier -- i.e. it is different for each relying party application. So if you are migrating identifies from an existing app to B2C, then you must map the "public" identifier, which is the **oid** claim, that is same for all RP apps.