# How to write to directory signin log during user journey

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented custom policies to link external accounts to B2C local users during signin, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722908/how-to-pre-create-business-customers-in-ad-b2c).  For context, I pre-create local users in the directory with their `signInName` equal to their issuer email address. When users from external AD tenants enter the sign flow, I can then look them up with the technical profile `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress`.

This works great and allows us to pre-provision and authorize users in our apps before the users' first signin attempt.  However it appears that no login events are being recorded in the SignIn logs accessible through the portal.

Am I missing something?  If not, seems I'll need to capture my own logs. I could write out to an Az Function from the User Journey, but it would really be preferred to write to the directory so logins events are visible in the portal.  Is there a way to do this?  I can easily call AzureAD GraphAPI if it offers the capability.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a sign-in log is only created for a local account sign-in, not an external account sign-in, as per your sign-in flow.

[The audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs), however, should contain the following activities:

- An **Issue an id_token to the application** or **Issue an authorization code to the application** activity containing the local account user identifier and, if an external identity provider was used, then the identity provider name, identity provider client identifier, and identity provider user identifier
- For a local account sign-in, a **Validate local account credentials** activity containing the local account user identifier and sign-in name; or
- For an external account sign-in, a **Federate with an identity provider** activity containing the identity provider name, identity provider client identifier, and identity provider user identifier

You can also create [a custom event from the sign-in policy to Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-guide-eventlogger-appins).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I like the App Insights solution for the a view of the last 90 days.  Beyond that I believe the App Insights data is purged barring some other config, but in that case I can fall back on the events in the audit logs you’ve described.

Comment: Hi @MarkArnold. Note that "Audit logs are only retained for seven days. Plan to download and store your logs using one of the methods shown below if you require a longer retention period." See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPadgett!!